# Python Transitions: how to map all possible transitions of an FSM to a graph

Tags: python, graphviz, transition, fsm, pygraphviz

I couldn't install pygraphviz on my Windows 10 system so as a workaround I am trying to store the states and transitions of the FSM in a separate graph. For example:

```
from transitions import Machine
from graphviz import Digraph

class Matter(object):
    pass

# The states
states=['hungry', 'satisfied', 'full', 'sick']

# And some transitions between states. 
transitions = [
     { 'trigger': 'eat', 'source': 'hungry', 'dest': 'satisfied' },
     { 'trigger': 'eat', 'source': 'satisfied', 'dest': 'full' },
     { 'trigger': 'eat', 'source': 'full', 'dest': 'sick' },
     { 'trigger': 'rest', 'source': ['satisfied', 'full', 'sick'], 'dest': 
      'hungry' }]


# Initialize
machine = Matter()
fsm = Machine(machine, states=states, transitions=transitions, initial=states[0])
dot = Digraph(comment='FSM')

src = machine.state

for event in transitions:
    machine.trigger(event['trigger'])
    dst = machine.state
    dot.edge(src,dst,event['trigger'])
    src = dst

print (dot)
```

Here my graph doesn't include all the possible transitions and includes only the sequential transitions.

Output:

```
digraph {
    hungry -> satisfied [label=eat]
    satisfied -> full [label=eat]
    full -> sick [label=eat]
    sick -> hungry [label=rest]
}
```

As you can see the multiple state transitions are not present in the graph. Is there a way I can trigger all the transitions and store it in the graph or do I have to write a custom code for all of this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transitions` organises transitions in events. An `Event` may contain several transitions, again organised in a dictionary. To achieve what you desire, first iterate over the event dictionary (key is the trigger name and value is the `Event` itself) to get the events. Then, iterate over `Event.transitions` (key is the source state and value is a list of applicable `Transition` objects) to get a list of transitions. Now, iterate over this list to get the source and destination of each transition. You can use the trigger name as a label if you like:

```
from transitions import Machine
from graphviz import Digraph


class Matter(object):
    pass


# The states
states = ['hungry', 'satisfied', 'full', 'sick']

# And some transitions between states.
transitions = [{'trigger': 'eat', 'source': 'hungry', 'dest': 'satisfied'},
               {'trigger': 'eat', 'source': 'satisfied', 'dest': 'full'},
               {'trigger': 'eat', 'source': 'full', 'dest': 'sick'},
               {'trigger': 'rest', 'source': ['satisfied', 'full', 'sick'],
                'dest': 'hungry'}]


# Initialize
machine = Matter()
fsm = Machine(machine, states=states, transitions=transitions, initial=states[0],
              auto_transitions=False)
dot = Digraph(comment='FSM')

for label, event in fsm.events.items():
    for event_transitions in event.transitions.values():
        for transition in event_transitions:
            dot.edge(transition.source, transition.dest, label)
print(dot)
```

Output:

```
// FSM
digraph {
    hungry -> satisfied [label=eat]
    satisfied -> full [label=eat]
    full -> sick [label=eat]
    satisfied -> hungry [label=rest]
    full -> hungry [label=rest]
    sick -> hungry [label=rest]
}
```

I also added `auto_transitions=False` to your `Machine`. This way `transitions` will not generate auto transitions (`to_<state_name>`) which would otherwise clutter your graph. Of course, you can tinker with `auto_transitions=True` or try to filter auto transitions from the graph as done in `transitions`' [diagrams extension](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/blob/8a70d0e29deac66ce877b9c684638692cea91db3/transitions/extensions/diagrams.py#L135).